# Upload & Convert file at AWS Lambda

Tags: php, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

Is there a away to send file to lambda directly via manual invoke method and then do some processing on the file like converting doc file to pdf and then return the file to the client?

I am using PHP to invoke Lambda, so far I was not able to find any satisfactory answer about it and I decided to ask about my concerns here.

What I have done so far is

- Created a Lambda Function
- Created a PHP Project
- Installed AWS SDK
- Configured Authorization and every other issues
- Made and invoke call to my lambda function from php and it works fine and returns the response

`Now I would like to send a file to Lambda for conversion and then get converted file in response of that request, all done Synchronously.`

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda has limits: Request body payload size (Event/asynchronous invocation) - 128 KB

Check all limits [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)

You can't upload a file into lambda directly, use S3 for that.
After uploading a file into S3 bucket you can use S3 Triggers to invoke lambda and download the file from s3

Comment: I am interested in this (RequestResponse/synchronous invocation) which has the max size of 6MB.

We can not even use the file in this mode ?

Comment: If the lambda invoked by a RequestResponse type the payload is 6MB. If its an event is 128K.